# approve error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to approve documents in asp.net when admin login then they approve documents 2 or 3 days ago code works fine now when i again open my project and approve documents it shows me error 
"Input string was in correct format "

here is the button code..

```
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connStr = 
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydms"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);


        try{
            mySQLconnection.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < Repeater2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList DropDownListcontrol =
            ((DropDownList)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DropDownList4"));
            Label DocId = ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DocId"));
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("approveddd", mySQLconnection);
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
             Convert.ToInt32((DocId.Text));

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
              Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =
              (Session["Login2"]);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                DMSLIB.Doc myDoc = new DMSLIB.Doc();
                myDoc.MarkDocAs(Convert.ToInt16(DocId.Text), 
             Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue));

            }
        }
           catch (Exception ex)
            {
                apfi.Text = "Error";
            }
         finally
        {
            mySQLconnection.Close();
        }
        }
```

please any one tell me where is the problem occur... ??

Comment: What line produces the error?

Comment: No, how about *you* tell is where the problem occurs? Also, include the full exception.

Comment: Looks like one of call to `cmd.Parameters.Add` failed. May be you are trying to set `SqlDbType.Int` value, which is not a valid integer string.

Comment: in this exception occur ... catch (Exception ex)

Comment: @user2931015 debugging as a common, informative and the best way to see what's happenning in the code. Why not using it?

Comment: i also set a breakpoint it shows me input string was not in correct format in catch now i cant understand where is the error occur  in try code..

Answer (score 0):

One of `DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue` or `DocId.Text` has string value that cannot be converted to Integer. Set a breakpoint and see what you have there. Breakpoint is a small red circle to the left of code lines that can be set by mouse click. Once application stops there you are able to see actual variables values by dragging mouse cursor over them.

Comment: @user2931015 Not all html elements values are posted back to server, but only some of them. You displayed Label.Text on page, but it doesnt return back to server when user submits form and thus ASP.NET is unable to restore your Label fully. Use HiddenField that can persist value, staying invisible on page but being sent back as user performs submit. I am not sure as didnt work with WebForms fo long, but there may be also a way to use viewstate to store this property in ViewState (google for Label.Text viewstate). And please accept this answer as it is correct. Thanks!

Comment: like this??    <td>
                                       
                                        <asp:Label Id="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>

                                      <%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                               <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HdnFileID" Value='<%# Eval("DocID") %>' />
                                    </td

Comment: @user2931015 im not sure for syntax, but yes, seems to be correct. On post back you read DocId value from the hidden field (not from label). Does it make sense?

Comment: @user2931015 If you have single DocId per web page then put that hidden field somewhere out of any loops (repeaters). Otherwise put it into the corresponding lines of repeater.

Comment: @user2931015 i would advice that before writing complicated code you clearly understand how GET and POST methods work as well as how webpage data and ASP.NET controls are bidirectionally bound (what's happening when webpage is rendered and how the posted back form values are bound back to controls; read about ViewState too). This is really interesting and greatly helps for sites programming.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot say for sure, you seem to have a type conversion issue cropping up.

However, your real problem is with your knowledge of debugging. I would advise that you work through some online tutorials on debugging in your IDE (Which I'm going to assume is Visual Studio) and learn about the different types of errors that crop up and what causes them. This will help you read stack traces for errors and understand them.

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 then this article helped me a lot to learn the basics of debugging very quickly. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn